# How should I transform ES6 node_modules with browserify and babelify?

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, ecmascript-6, browserify

I'm using gulp, browserify and babelify in order to use ES6 syntax in my project. As soon as I import a node_module, which was also written in ES6, gulp throws an error: `'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'`

I've read the proposed solutions on [babelify's github page](https://github.com/babel/babelify#why-arent-files-in-node_modules-being-transformed). In short, the two possibilities are:

1. Add a browserify option to the affected node_module's package.json
2. Configure gulp, so that browserify tries to transform all files with babelify (and add an ignore-option for unnecessary files).

The first option would prevent others from being able to clone my project and get it up and running right away. Is there a workaround, perhaps using an npm postinstall script?

The second option seems like an overkill. Is there a more elegant solution for this?

Comment: Normally you'd compile your code before publishing it, then Browserify and such don't need to know anything about ES6. That's the most common workflow anyway.

Comment: So the author of that particular npm module shouldn't have published the ES6 code, if I understand correctly.

Comment: Babelify does have an [`only` option](https://github.com/babel/babelify#additional-options). You could configure it as a global transform and use `only` to limit the `node_modules` that it transforms.

Comment: Thanks, @cartant! If you could post an example, I would accept it as  answer to this question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Babelify](https://github.com/babel/babelify) has an [`only`](https://github.com/babel/babelify#additional-options) option that can be used to avoid transpiling files that don't match a regular expression. When combined with Browserify's `global` option (by default, transforms are not applied to files within the `node_modules` directory), you can selectively transpile files within `node_modules`.

With this example configuration:

```
browserify({ entries: ["index.js"] })
  .transform("babelify", {
    global: true,
    only: /^(?:.*\/node_modules\/(?:a|b)\/|(?!.*\/node_modules\/)).*$/,
    presets: ["es2015"]
  })
  .bundle()
  .pipe(fs.createWriteStream("bundle.js"));
```

files not within `node_modules` will not be compiled unless they are in one of:

- `/node_modules/a`
- `/node_modules/b`

If you have only one directory under `node_modules` that you want transpiled, you can simplify the regular expression to:

```
/^(?:.*\/node_modules\/a\/|(?!.*\/node_modules\/)).*$/
```

and if you have more, you can add them:

```
/^(?:.*\/node_modules\/(?:a|b|c|d)\/|(?!.*\/node_modules\/)).*$/
```

Comment: I am also getting same error , to what I have to replace this index.js and bundle.js (I am including the quilljs in my bower component in index.html)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41800618/bower-component-quilljs-editor-module-es6-is-failing-while-running-gulp-build