# How to ignore a particular bower component being installed which is dependent on other bower component

Tags: gulp, bower, quill

I am trying to install ng-quill which takes quill as its dependency which I do not want to  install and use cdn instead, due to some compilation issue, just trying if this can help.

[Bower component Quilljs editor module (ES6) is failing while running gulp build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41800618/bower-component-quilljs-editor-module-es6-is-failing-while-running-gulp-build)

```
"overrides": {
     "ngQuill" : {
         "dependencies" : []
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27791606) has the solution to your problem. It boils down to adding the following to your `.bowerrc`:

```
{
  "ignoredDependencies": [
    "quill"
  ]
}
```