# How to load a node module which is in ES6 in angular js app?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bower, quill

I am using quillJs text editor it works fine if I use cdn in loclahost but not in build files,

**Localhost development:** 
using cdn for the quill library.
It works fine if I use the cdn and ng-quill from the dependency

**In production**
While doing the build through bower package, it states error.
If I don't use the bower package and include the cdn it works in loclahost without build however when I do a build it do not load the cdn library also.

I am trying this error to solve for long

My related ques(may help for more reason):

[Bower component Quilljs editor module (ES6) is failing while running gulp build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41800618/bower-component-quilljs-editor-module-es6-is-failing-while-running-gulp-build)

[How to ignore a particular bower component being installed which is dependent on other bower component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41802349/how-to-ignore-a-particular-bower-component-being-installed-which-is-dependent-on)

```
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
Error: scripts/vendor.js: error: couldn't process source due to parse error
'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module' (176000:0)
```

**index.html**
This works in dev more but not in build
    
    </script>-->

The library has link to (after doing npm install quill and ng-quill are installed in bower_components)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../bower_components/quill/quill.js"></script> //it has es6 so I used CDN one that is working fine
```

Comment: this isn't making any sense.  are you *sure* you are including the right library in your production code?  ES6 code requires a transpiler to run in the browser, so generally libraries written in ES6 are distributed after being transpiled.  Are you trying to build the library from source without a transpiler for some reason?

Comment: updated the ques, how to run a transpiler I tried with bablify but don't know what sequence to be used, I have added link to other question which have gulp file code.