# Babelify imports in a reactJS application does not replace let declarations to var

Tags: javascript, import, ecmascript-6, gulp, babelify

I built a small ReactJS application that runs in the browser, i am having issues with older browser versions (especially on iOS devices), the application is built with node and browserify/babelify

I have the following gulpfile setup:

`gulp.task('build', function () {
    return browserify({entries: './src/app.jsx', extensions: ['.jsx'], debug: true})
        .transform(babelify)
        .bundle()
        .pipe(source('app.js'))
        .pipe(buffer())
        .pipe(minify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/layout/lib'))
})`

with the following config:

`{
  "presets": ["env"],
  "plugins": ["transform-react-jsx"],
}`

one of my react components imports a module like so:

`import ethereum_address from 'ethereum-address'`

the code works but for some reason the bablified bundle still has `use strict` and some `let` declarations that come from that specific module.

is there anything i can do to force the babelify to actually replace those declarations as needed so this code will work on older browsers?

Comment: looki here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39321384/how-should-i-transform-es6-node-modules-with-browserify-and-babelify

Answer (score 0):

After digging around and seeing what Elin Gersin found i now understand the problem.

it seems that when transforming it is required to specify the `global` property so the transformer knows to run on all imports and not just the react components.

the resulting gulp task looks like this:

`gulp.task('build', ['sass'], function () {
    return browserify({entries: './src/app.jsx', debug: true})
        .transform(babelify, {
            global: true,
            only: /^(?:.*\/node_modules\/ethereum-address\/|(?!.*\/node_modules\/)).*$/
        })
        .bundle()
        .pipe(source('app.js'))
        .pipe(buffer())
        .pipe(minify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/layout/lib'))
})`